# "Failed to start session" after uninstalling PulseAudio

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, pulseaudio

I had downloaded and installed PulseAudio, as I read that it could possibly work with 14.04; it didn't. I uninstalled it through `Synaptic Package Manager`, then while uninstalling, icons started to be removed automatically from the launch bar. I can't remember what I was trying to do, but I was trying to use the System Settings, but it wouldn't load, so I restarted. I was prompted for my password on boot; but I have that disabled. When I typed my password I got `Failed to start session`. I tried logging into a guest session too, same problem.

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, and don't have a clue how to resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Switch to tty1 Ctrl+Alt+F1, then login and run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. reboot and try login again.